# How to place on spinbutton on top of another in NumericUpDown? | Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

Default `NumericUpDown` looks like that:

[image],

and because of buttons take a lot of place I want to make it more Windows form style, like this:

[image].

I've tried to play with `ButtonSpinner` Styles, but didn't work out, it shrinks the whole `NumericUpDown`, not only `ButtonSpinner` (even if I write another style for `NumericUpDown`).

```
<Style Selector="ButtonSpinner">
  <Setter Property="Height">
    <Setter.Value>
      10
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Width">
    <Setter.Value>
      25
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I should do to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [@radoslawik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12473121/radoslawik) proposed a good solution, but there was one problem -- he linked to nightly build of Avalonia and you may use another version. If you are you must find source code of your version (they are tagged in [github](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/tags)) and look up styles there. For my version (0.10.18 -- it's last non-preview available at the moment) solution is next:

```
<Window.Styles>
  <Style Selector="NumericUpDown /template/ ButtonSpinner">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <ControlTemplate>
        <DataValidationErrors>
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                  MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}">
            <DockPanel>
              <UniformGrid Rows="2" Name="PART_SpinnerPanel"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                          IsVisible="{TemplateBinding ShowButtonSpinner}">
                <RepeatButton Name="PART_IncreaseButton"
                              Classes="ButtonSpinnerRepeatButton"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}">
                  <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Width="16"
                        Height="8"
                        Stretch="Uniform"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Data="{StaticResource ButtonSpinnerIncreaseButtonIcon}" />
                </RepeatButton>

                <RepeatButton Name="PART_DecreaseButton"
                              Classes="ButtonSpinnerRepeatButton"
                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}">
                  <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Width="16"
                        Height="8"
                        Stretch="Uniform"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Data="{StaticResource ButtonSpinnerDecreaseButtonIcon}" />
                </RepeatButton>
              </UniformGrid>

              <ContentPresenter Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </DockPanel>
          </Border>
        </DataValidationErrors>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Window.Styles>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. You could modify the `ButtonSpinner` template (or `NumericUpDown /template/ ButtonSpinner` template) to use the `UniformGrid` with 2 rows instead of [`StackPanel` with horizontal orientation](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls/ButtonSpinner.xaml#L94) used by the `Fluent` theme. However you may encounter some problems with missing static resources, so you have to remember to include them in your file.
2. You could use the `Simple` theme instead of `Fluent` one. It uses a template with [`UniformGrid` with 2 rows](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Simple/Controls/ButtonSpinner.xaml#L35) by default, but it would change the look of all controls.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I didn't find how I can made that. I've tried change line in `App.axaml` to change style, but it did not give any results (actually it's just fails to compile -- some result there is). I'll make some attempts on modifying control template, but I'm not sure that it'll be something good.

Comment: Yeap, I found how I can make it. There was one problem with your solution and I've described that in my answer and if there wasn't one I would mark your answer as solution.